# Save variable with command substitution... command not found

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to save into a bash variable a string after a `grep` and `sed` treatment.
Here my code :

```
echo ${plan} | grep -e '^\S' -e 'Home directory:' | sed -e 's/Home directory: //'

/home/james
```

That's what I need to save into a variable... so I tried :

```
HOME_DIRECTORY=$(${plan} | $(grep -e '^\S' -e 'Home directory:') | $(sed -e 's/Home directory: //'))
```

and

```
HOME_DIRECTORY=`${plan} | grep -e '^\S' -e 'Home directory:' | sed -e 's/Home directory: //'`
```

But both give me :

```
line 121: Home: command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

Change you command to ,

```
HOME_DIRECTORY=$(echo ${plan} | grep -e '^\S' -e 'Home directory:' | sed -e 's/Home directory: //')
```

That is, you need to include the whole command inside `$()`.